# How to set up Linear mixed model in SPSS?

Tags: mixed-model, linear

I am trying to find out how inflammatory markers change in response to a mechanical device change. I have daily readings for the 5 days before the event and for the 5 days after the event. I am expecting a rise in inflammatory markers in the pre readings followed by a fall after the device change. I also need to find out how the change differs in two subgroups (sample sizes of the subgroups are n=21 and n=88). The aim is to find out if the change is significant, to consider these markers as predictors of the device failing and hence needing to be changed.